# Java Android refer to a non-final answer inside an inner class

Tags: java, android

Yes, I have seen the other questions and i have read through them and i have tried to understand it but i think i am struggling to make it work in my scenario.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randNumber;
long chosenNumber;
String answer;
while (questionCount < 3) {
//---get all titles---
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
    do {          
        DisplayTitle(c);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
db.close();

//---pick a question---
db.open();
randNumber = rand.nextInt(3);
chosenNumber = (long) randNumber;

String questionPrompt = db.pickQuestion(chosenNumber);
while (questionPrompt == null)
{
    randNumber = rand.nextInt(3);
    chosenNumber = (long) randNumber;
    questionPrompt = db.pickQuestion(chosenNumber);
}

answer = db.pickQuestion(chosenNumber);
question.setText(questionPrompt);
db.close();

btnclickme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String str = txtname.getText().toString();
            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "That is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "That is incorrect, try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I get the error cannot refer to a non-final variable answer... whatever when i am trying to check if the text from the user is equal to the string answer. My question is, how do i make it so i can edit the answer (i am going to continually call different questions in like put this in a while loop and change the answer over and over) so every time i make the answer a final, it does not change for the next question. Do i have to create a variable for every question? help!

Comment: I think you want to make it a member variable instead method-local.

Comment: I cant make it final, i have plans to change the answer variable. This is just for one question in my app, but i am going to put some loops around this (not sure exactly how yet) so that it will continually call the questions from the database and change the questionPrompt and answer variables to the next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is to make it `final`. If this sounds counter-intuitive, note that final means the pointer's address cannot change... However, the value stored there can. So you could use a mutable data structure, like a `java.lang.StringBuilder`, and modify it while still being `final`, and call `.toString()` on it when you need the value.

Comment: This is it! thank you so much. I have been looking for hours online for a solution. never heard of stringbuilder class. just started messing with java a couple days ago, i mainly use c++ in my courses. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. There is also StringBuffer, both do the trick though. Oh how much I miss good old C++!

Comment: This will fail, though, if you have more than one answer being listened for at once. All of your listeners will be expecting the value most recently set to the StringBuilder, not the value that was there when the listener was created.

Answer (score 0):

Make it an instance variable like the following:

```
public class Test
{
     // Instance Variable
     private int x;

     public void OnCreate ...
```

Comment: This does not work with strings. at least when i try it just gives me errors of an illegal modifier

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the value then make it a member variable instead of a method-local:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private String answer;
```

Comment: This does not work with strings. at least when i try it just gives me errors of a illegal modifier.

Comment: You can't use access modifier inside a method. Declare it inside the class but outside any method or other kinds of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a final local variable here if you move the loop body out into another method. It's OK for a final variable to have a different value each time a method is called.

It might be clearer, though, if you used a named class for the click listener:

```
class AnswerListener extends View.OnClickListener {
   String answer;
   EditText txtname;

   AnswerListener(String answer, EditText txtname) {
      this.answer = answer;
      this.txtname = txtname;
   }

   public void onClick(View v) { ... }
}
```

Then you can just do `btnclickme.setOnClickListener(new AnswerListener(answer, txtname))`, passing the values explicitly instead of relying on them being picked up from final variables.